# Is there any way to characterize null space of system on polynomial equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Taking motivation from an under-determined system of linear equations (more variables ($n$) than equations ($m$)), we can say that the dimension of the null space is: $n-m$.

Can we comment something similar about the system of polynomial equations ?

Comment: How do you define this dimension? The set of zeroes of a system of polynomial equations is not a subspace in general. On the other hand, the dimension of the null space for linear equations is $\ge n-m$, that's all you can say in general.

Comment: It's complicated. Working over the reals, $x^2+y^2=-1$ has no solutions, $x^2+y^2=0$ has a single point, $x^2+y^2=1$ has a curve (a circle, to be precise). There's more uniformity working over the complex numbers, and algebraic geometry is the field of mathematics where you'll find the answers.

Comment: The zero set is an affine variety.

Comment: You are asking about the foundations of Algebraic Geometry :-)

Comment: @Wuestenfux: an *algebraic`* variety. An affine variety is a translated of a subspace.

Comment: @Bernard: I'd call a translated subspace an affine subspace.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Great! I have gotten an excuse to explore Algebraic Geometry now.

Comment: Can we say something about the geometry of under-determined system of quadratic equations? Or in general, something like $A \textbf{x}^2 + A \textbf{x} = \textbf{y}$, where $\textbf{x}^2$ denotes element-wise square of the vector $\textbf{x}$

$A$ is $m \times n$ matrix with $m<n$ and $\textbf{x}$ is $n \times 1$ vector.